# What is ICriticalNotifyCompletion for?

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm trying to understand how the C# async mechanisms actually works and one source of confusion is the `ICriticalNotifyCompletion` interface.

The interface provides two methods: `OnCompleted(Action)`, inherited from `INotifyCompletion` and `UnsafeOnCompleted(Action)`. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.icriticalnotifycompletion?view=net-5.0) has the exact same description for both methods: *"Schedules the continuation action that's invoked when the instance completes."*.

Only difference is that a remark on `UnsafeOnCompleted(Action)` states that it doesn't have to  *"propagate ExecutionContext information"*, whatever that means. It is nowhere explicitly stated that `OnCompleted(Action)` has to *"propagate ExecutionContext information"*.

The documentation on [awaitable expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#awaitable-expressions) states that `UnsafeOnCompleted(Action)` is called if the awaiter implements `ICriticalNotifyCompletion`. So implementing `ICriticalNotifyCompletion` makes `OnCompleted(Action)` redundant?

Why would an awaiter implement `ICriticalNotifyCompletion`? What are the implications of `TaskAwaiter` implementing `ICriticalNotifyCompletion`? What if it didn't?

Comment: Found a bit more details in [Async Task types](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/475c75bfabf77f8f5ad4be0e84486951f02cb30b/proposals/csharp-7.0/task-types.md) proposal. However, the real reason can be explained by MS guys, I suppose

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "propagate ExecutionContext information", whatever that means

There's actually no good exhaustive definition for this, and I certainly won't try to provide one because I know I'll miss something important. I do know, though, that flowing `ExecutionContext` is *necessary* for security reasons - this is why all methods that don't flow the context use the `Unsafe` naming convention. [Stephen Toub has this to say](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext/):

> ExecutionContext is all about “ambient” information, meaning that it stores data relevant to the current environment or “context” in which you’re running... one of the contexts contained by ExecutionContext is SecurityContext, which maintains information like the current “principal” and information about code access security (CAS) denies and permits.

So the first thing to recognize is that the `ExecutionContext` *must* be flowed. The next piece of the puzzle is again [described by Stephen Toub](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/whats-new-for-parallelism-in-net-4-5-beta/). For historical context, this description is when `async`/`await` was still a prerelease (but publicly available) technology:

> many folks didn’t realize that their awaiters needed to flow ExecutionContext in order to ensure context flowed across await points... [So] we’ve modified the async method builders in the Framework (e.g. AsyncTaskMethodBuilder)... The builders now themselves flow ExecutionContext across await points, taking that responsibility away from the awaiters.

Originally, the awaiters would flow `ExecutionContext`, but this was changed before the official `async`/`await` release so that the *builders* flow `ExecutionContext`. Naturally, this means the awaiters no longer have to flow `ExecutionContext`; if they did, asynchronous code would end up flowing it twice (where a "flow" is a "capture" followed by an "execute delegate in this captured context").

Now there's enough information to answer these questions:

> Why would an awaiter implement ICriticalNotifyCompletion? What are the implications of TaskAwaiter implementing ICriticalNotifyCompletion? What if it didn't?

If an awaiter doesn't implement `ICriticalNotifyCompletion`, then an `await` using that code will end up flowing the `ExecutionContext` twice (one by the awaiter, and once by the `async` method builder). It's not going to break anything; it'll just be less efficient than it could be.

> So implementing ICriticalNotifyCompletion makes OnCompleted(Action) redundant?

Not quite. Again, [delegating to Stephen Toub](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/whats-new-for-parallelism-in-net-4-5-beta/):

> If you’re building an assembly with AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute (APTCA) applied to it, you need to ensure that any publicly exposed APIs from your assembly correctly flow ExecutionContext across async points… failure to do so can be a big security hole. As awaiter types will often be implemented in APTCA assemblies, and since OnCompleted could be called directly by a user (even though it’s really meant to be used by the compiler), OnCompleted needs to flow ExecutionContext... we also have UnsafeOnCompleted, which doesn’t need to flow ExecutionContext, but which is also marked as SecurityCritical, such that partially trusted code can’t call it.

with the conclusion:

> If you’re implementing your own awaiter, whenever possible implement both INotifyCompletion and ICriticalNotifyCompletion, flowing ExecutionContext in the former and not flowing it in the latter.  The only good reason not to implement both is if you’re implementing an awaiter in a situation where you can’t flow ExecutionContext, e.g. where your awaiter is partially trusted or where you otherwise don’t have the ability to use ExecutionContext, or where the APIs on which your awaiter relies doesn’t give you any option as to whether to flow context or not… in such cases, you can just implement INotifyCompletion.

I would modify this conclusion only slightly. In the almost-a-decade since the above was written, I would say that it is *not* common to use APTCA assemblies. I.e., .NET Core has no support for partial trust at all. For .NET Core, I believe you could say that `OnCompleted` is redundant. However, this distinction is still important in the .NET Framework world, where `OnCompleted` is necessary for awaiters in partial-trust assemblies.

So I would say: When implementing an awaiter, always implement `ICriticalNotifyCompletion` if you *can* implement it (i.e., without flowing `ExecutionContext`). Otherwise, just keep the regular `OnCompleted` implementation.

Comment: I kind of get the feeling that while it's technically possible to write your own task-like type, it's not really something you're expected to be doing.

Comment: @TrayMan: Agreed. They were occasionally useful in high-performance scenarios, but now that `ValueTask<T>` / `ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<T>` are in .NET, I don't see much use for them moving forwards.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this after reading pretty much all the same Stephen Toub posts. I'm more and more getting the feeling that there is no way in hell partial trust *actually* works reliably; that stuff seems to be the mother of all minefields.